# How to implement ControlValueAccessor on downgraded Angular component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have an Angular component that implements `ControlValueAccessor`, but the `writeValue` method is never called with the initial value from `ngModel`.

template:

`<my-comp [(ngModel)]="$ctrl.activeUser"></my-comp>`

the component is downgraded to AngularJS via:

```
.directive('myComp', downgradeComponent({
  component: MyComp,
  inputs: [],
  outputs: [],
}));
```

I tried adding `ngModel` to `inputs` and `outputs` but it's not working.

Comment: Is it possible to get some more code?? Where is involved the usage and the definition of `writeValue`. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to initialize the `$ctrl.activeUser` to null and to assign his value after page rendering?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `ng-model` attribute instead of `[(ngModel)]`, like this: `<my-comp ng-model="$ctrl.activeUser"></my-comp>`

From the angular docs:

```
 * 3. `ng-model` is controlled by AngularJS and communicates with the downgraded Angular component
 *    by way of the `ControlValueAccessor` interface from @angular/forms. Only components that
 *    implement this interface are eligible.
 *
 * ## Supported Features
 *
 * - Bindings:
 *   - Attribute: `<comp name="World">`
 *   - Interpolation:  `<comp greeting="Hello {{name}}!">`
 *   - Expression:  `<comp [name]="username">`
 *   - Event:  `<comp (close)="doSomething()">`
 *   - ng-model: `<comp ng-model="name">`
```